# Java I/O для объёмных данных

Tags: оптимизация, файлы, java

Нужен совет опытных по поводу производительности Java I/O и много другого. Задачка такая - в нескольких потоках клиент шлет http post запрос весом до 1 мб каждый, в ответ приходят еще больший по весу (2-4 мб) ответ в формате JSON, который нужно спарсить и аккуратно завернуть в .csv файл. Количество запросов может доходить до десятков тысяч,все ответы сервера пишутся в 1 файл. Сервер один и тот же. (что делать с Keep-Alive ? ) . Соответственно возникает вопрос - а какие инструменты при этом использовать ?

1. Соединение: HttpClient / HttpUrlConnection /Netty/etc
2. Чтение ответа : BufferedReader/Scanner/etc
3. Чем Json парсить ? jackson/gson/simple json
4. Чем писать в файл, и нужно ли вообще писать во время работы или же лучше кидать в какой нибудь ArrayList, потом спарсить и записать.

В общем, буду рад любым советам и подсказкам)

Вопрос не мой, просто помогаю человеку :)

Comment: Что характеризует величина "Количество запросов может доходить до десятков тысяч"? Это в секунду что ли?

Comment: @a_gura Десятки (если не сотни гиг в секунду) -- не так уж и слабо. По 100Мбит-ной сетке столько не прокачать.

Comment: @alexlz я потому и задаю вопрос автору.

Comment: Молчит автор. Ой, я не думаю, что в секунду ;) , скорее в день

Comment: А во ВКонтакте ему ответили, бывает же :) ! http://vk.com/javaclub?w=wall-1279_11162%2Fall

Comment: @Михаил М, и в самом деле, Denis Borovikov (по ссылке из Вашего коммента) очень грамотно ответил.

Comment: Автор так и не объявился, но всем спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Для объемных файлов конкретный api особо не влияет на скорость передачи, все упрется в возможности железа. Заморачиваться с nio стоит, если есть например много легких соединений, и есть проблемы с переключениями контекстов. Так что выбирайте удобный, отлаженный api. Я бы взял apache http client 4.

2) BufferedReader - хорошее решение

3) Я бы взял jackson - мощный и быстрый. Gson скорее более специализированное решение для конвертации между бинами и json.

4) Писать лучше во время работы из другого потока, будет pipelinig. И запись конечно должна быть буферизованной, например через BufferedWriter.

Keep alive лучше выключить. Файлы большие, время установки соединений ничтожно меньше времени передачи. Только морока будет с настройкой сервера.

Еще советую на клиенте и сервере установить размеры tcp буфферов в один мегабайт, алгоритм нигла оставить включенным, scaling tcp окна тоже оставить включенным.

И еще общий совет: делай каждую стадию отдельной группой потоков, потоки соединяй очередями. Это называется SEDA. Так ты сможешь получить максимальную пропускную способность. Кстати, увеличение длин очередей увеличивается пропускную способность, но ухудшает latency. Имей в виду.

```
  Автор ответа - Денис Боровиков, [http://vk.com/id36765][1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Здравствуйте [@Михаил М](/users/12913/%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BB-%D0%BC). сказать, что Вы как-то смутно задали вопрос это тоже самое что вообще ничего не сказать).

производительности Java I/O  - во первых уточнили бы какую яву собираетесь использовать. в любом случае у Вас будет многопоточность сразу советую смотреть в сторону [java concurrency apis](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html). думаю появится много проблемм и ожиданий в очередях пока Вы будете парсить такие обьемы а потом еще и записывать в один файл. - это какая-то жесть(возможно я не правильно понял задачу)

тем более что запросов до десятков тысяч.

что значит что делать с keep-alive ?, если я правильно понимаю у каждого request/response - свое время жизни и регулироваться они будут самостоятельно.

ну да и по порядку:

1 - для запросов мне в мобильных разработках помогла и хорошо себя зарекомендовала вот эта либа [http-request](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request) - там сразу на страничке все описано в доль и поперек

2 - здесь тоже все может выполнить предыдущая либа.

3 - gson - себя зарекомендовал с очень хорошей стороны, хоть и не без косяков))

4 - я не понимаю почему все в один файл, возможно стоило вначале описать функциональность которую Вы хотите в итоге добиться, я бы хронил уже готовые для записи .csv  в мапке и завел бы отдельный поток который бы и записывал их поочередно. это спосет Вас от многопоточного доступа к файловой системе. и позволит как минимум всем потокам по очереди получать право на запись в мапку, и постоянное право у записывающего потока на чтение из нее.

касаемо первых двух пунктов могу сказать еще только что если пользоваться стандартными средствами то я бы использовал BufferedInputStream и HttpUrlConnection